# SQLite Query WHERE clause for column type INTEGER

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite table consisting of 2 columns types; `VARCHAR` and `INTEGER`. I need to select all of the relevant values in the `VARCHAR` column IF the `INTEGER` value in the same row is equal to `0`

A sample of my code:

```
public static final String CreateDateTable = "create table " + DATE_TABLE
        + " (" + DATE + " VARCHAR(30) not null, " + INTEGER_COLUMN
        + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";

    String[] column = new String[] { DATE};
    String WHERE = "CAST("+INTEGER_COLUMN+" as VARCHAR) = ?";
    String[] WHEREARGS = new String[] { "0" };
    Cursor c;
    c = ourDatabase.query(DATE_TABLE, column, WHERE, WHEREARGS, null, null,
            null);
```

All rows are being returned, the `WHERE` clause appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to cast the integer column as `TEXT`,
The following code returned the correct results.

`String WHERE = "CAST("+INTEGER_COLUMN+" as TEXT) = ?";`

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of output value that you would expect? If just the varchar column, then

```
SELECT charCol
FROM table
WHERE table.intCol = 0;
```

Comment: just the varchar column

Comment: i tried your code as your have suggested which also returns the entire column `c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT "+DATE+" FROM "+DATE_TABLE+" WHERE "+DATE_TABLE+"."+NUM_SMOKES+" =?" ,new String[]{"0"});`. I have updated my question with the `String` used to create the table, if that is of any help. Any suggestions?

Comment: The type i expect in return is INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
String[] column = { DATE };
String where = INTEGER_COLUMN + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = { "0" };

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(
    DATE_TABLE, column, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

The cast to VARCHAR is redundant.

However, it really shouldn't cause all rows to be returned. So, my guess would be either there's something wrong with the way you insert the values, or the way you look at the results.

A more complete code sample might help figure out which.

**EDIT:**

I tried the updated code you posted, including the table creation. It doesn't actually compile, but assuming you meant `+ " INTEGER DEFAULT 0,)";` and not `+ " INTEGER DEFAULT 0,")";`, it works, and still only returns the correct rows.

Again, you should probably post the code you use to insert the values, how you query the DB, and exactly what results you get, if you expect us to be able to find the problem.

Comment: i will edit the code to provide a more complete overview. I have tried the above code before posting my question as my original code, and after some research it was suggested to try `CAST`, but that also did not work. Although, i am certain of the values inside of the table,

Comment: My apologies, i had edited the code to make it relevant to the question, and in doing so had an error. It has being fixed now.